# sql Point (geography Data Type) lat and long reversed

Tags: sql, geo

When i create a [Point (geography Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) the documentation tells me lat first.

But when i do this and check the lat and long are reversed.

I use this query to check:

```
DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(51.486625 5.380910)';

select @g.Lat as lat,@g.Long as long
```

i get this result:

| lat | long |
| --- | --- |
| 5,38091 | 51,486625 |

Is the documentation wrong or am i doing something wrong?

I tested this on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit) version 14.0.1000.169
an on azure SQL windows database.

When i reverse the values in the constructor of geography it seems to be correct.
This indicates to me that the documentation is wrong

Comment: your point and that of the mentioned in the documatation are different, so bit are correct

Comment: @nbk can you point me to the correct documentation?

Comment: here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stpointfromtext-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16 see where the text is explained about wkt write